# MongoDB - Don't Average Fields w/ No Value

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have MongoDB documents like this:

```
reports: {
    "2014-10-20": {
      aA: 577.5,
      aB: 537,
      aC: 521,
}
```

In some cases, the value of one of these dictionary items is not known.

In other words, a document could look like this:

```
reports: {
    "2014-10-20": {
      aA: 577.5,
      aB: 537,
      aC: None,
}
```

When I average fields like `aC` (in the second example above), how do I ensure fields with no value (`None` or similar) are not counted?

Should I set them to `None`, leave them empty, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are talking about the math in the context of some application code in mongoengine or simply using the [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

However, in both case you have to put the empty/unknown/unset attribute to 0 to be able to calculate the average,

If you are using the Aggregation Pipeline you can use the **[$ifNull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull)** operator, if the attribute is

```
{
  ...
  aC : null
  ...
}
```

The aggregation will look like

```
db.test.aggregate([
 { $project: {  "aC" : { $ifNull: [ "$aC", 0 ] }  } },
 {  $group : { _id : "key" ,   "avg" :  {$avg : "$aC"}  }   }
]);
```

Comment: So, this would not use `0` as a value for the averaging calculation? In other words, is it `(2 + 1 + 0) / 3` or `(2 + 1) / 2` (what I want).

Comment: It WILL use 0 in the $avg. The $ifNull operator is to replace a null by a 0 to be able to use the value in the average calulcation